# DateTime2 formart conversion to Swift Date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, utc

I have a date string coming from back-end as "2022-08-16T13:44:11.8743234". Date formatting and conversion is the oldest skill in the book but I cannot figure out why I'm unable to convert that string to a Date object in Swift iOS. I just get nil with any source format I specify.

```
private func StringToDate(dateString: String) -> Date?
{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.[nnnnnnn]"
    let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
    return date //this is nil every time
}
```

DateTime2 is a more precise SQL Server extension of the normal C# DateTime, hence why the date string has 7 decimal places afters the seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get YYYY, DD and [nnnnnnnn] from?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i tried many options, and that was one naive one from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: But this is Swift and not MS SQL so maybe check out the documentation for the language you are using.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson makes sense. I was just giving context as to why the date string is a bit longer than the usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the way you are handling the millisecond part is wrong. We use usually `.SSS` for milliseconds. Take a look at [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) it shows all the symbols related to date format.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale     = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2022-08-16T13:44:11.8743234")
print(date)
```

In addition to that you are using `DD` for day. `DD` means the day of the year(numeric). So it should be `dd`. Same case is applied for the year as well.

Comment: If you could add an explanation on what is going on with the Locale that would be perfect please.

Comment: The locale isn't relevant here

Comment: Note that this would use the current timezone when parsing the date string. OP should make sure the date string is not UTC when using this approach otherwise he should set the formatter timezone fixed to UTC

Comment: @LeoDabus how do you do that?